# error mldivide Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

```
format long
syms x landa
eps=10^-6; %we bound the error to closer to the exact solution
e=exp(1); % e number e=2.7
f=inline('x+1.0000e-006*exp(80*x)-5*landa','x','landa');% this is f(x,landa) function
ff=subs(x+1.0000e-006*exp(80*x)-5*landa',{x,landa}); 
dif_f=diff(ff); % to get the derivative
f1=inline(dif_f);%this is our f'(x) funciton
landa=linspace(0,1,101);
%landa=0.01;
deltalanda=0.01;

x0=0;
x=x0;
while landa<1
  for k=0:1000
    y=x;
    x=y-(f(x,landa)/f1(x))
    kk=f(x,landa)
    if f(x,landa)<=eps % we continue to find the x if it is found break the iteration 
       break
       landa=landa+deltalanda;
       deltalanda=deltalanda*2;
    end
  end
    deltalanda=deltalanda/2;
    landa=landa+deltalanda;
    landaa=landa;
    ff=subs(f,landa,landaa);
    dif_f=diff(ff);
    f1=inline(dif_f);
    x=0;
end
```

Can anyone please tell me why am I receiving the error in this line `x=y-(f(x,landa)/f1(x))`. It says matrix dimension error.

Comment: Probably because it must be a NxN matrix? There is too much code and too little context for anybody to give you help.

Answer (score 0):

What are the dimensions of `f(x,landa)` and `f1(x)` when you get the error?  You can either set a breakpoint, or tell the debugger to stop on errors, and examine the size of the output of both functions.

I suspect that you may be wanting element-wise division (`./`) rather than matrix division (`/`).  Either way though, using break-points and/or the debugger will help you a ton.